# Registration of multiple commands in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to understand the extension activation routine and maybe someone can help me.

In the file `package.json` there is the `activationEvents` node, where I define when the extension will be activated (e.g. when executing a command via `onCommand`). [See help](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/activation-events)

From code documentation of the sample extension, I understand that the extension will only be activated on the very first execution of the command.

What happens when I define multiple commands in the extension? I would register all the commands in the `activate` function and add them to the `activationEvents`:

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:extension.testCommand1",
    "onCommand:extension.testCommand2",
    "onCommand:extension.testCommand3"
],
```

Will the `activate` function only be called once when any of the commands was executed the very first time? Or will it call the function for the first execution of `extension.testCommand1`, `extension.testCommand2` and `extension.testCommand3` (--> three times)?

I'm also writing a language server and would like to put everything in the same extension. Is this possible or do I need to create two additional extensions (client and server)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, it will be called exactly one time, only when the first activation event occurs. If you're interested in verifying this yourself, set the activation events in `package.json` to:

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:js",
    "onLanguage:python",
    "onLanguage:ruby"
],
```

Then set a breakpoint in the activation method in your extension, press F5 to start debugging, and change the language mode via the command palette to js, python, and ruby. You'll see that the break-point is only hit the first time.

Regarding your second question, it probably depends on what your language service needs to do. If you want to do something as complex as the typescript language service, you might need both. If you want to make something that lints, provides hover tips, or more, but isn't quite as complex as typescript, you can do it one extension.

I'm personally following the example of the php service for my language extension. The team did a good job with it and the features are well separated and easy to understand. You can view the source of the php service [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/php).

Comment: Wow that's great, thanks for sharing the link to the php service, it will help me a lot. I'm creating a very similiar extension to support another script language. The language support itself and snippets are already done, also a command to open the online documentation wiki for specific commands, but the language service for autocompletion and maybe some other points like references are missing until yet. But now I'm sure that I'm able to implement the missing parts, thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Do you mind if I ask which language it's for?

Comment: It's SQF, used to create modifications for the game Arma by Bohemia Interactive.